# Getting the pathVariable in Feign

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm trying to log 3rd party API request details and was able to log URL, request and response body.

**Here's my sample feign client method:**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{name}")
Customer getDetails(@PathVariable(name = "name") List<String> name);
```

Here's the method where I intercepted the response in feign and was able to log the url, request and response.

```
public class FeignResponseDelegate extends Default {

@Override 
public Response execute(Request request, Request.Options options) throws IOException {
    Response response = super.execute(request, options);


    Request.Body requestBody = request.requestBody();
    InputStream responseBodyInputStream = response.body().asInputStream();
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(responseBodyInputStream);


    logger.debug("Request URL {}", request.url());
    logger.debug("Request Request body {}", requestBody.length() > 0 ? requestBody.asString() : null);
    logger.debug("Response Body {}", IOUtils.toString(responseBodyInputStream));

    // logger.debug("Path Variables: {}".....
    // how to log the path variables?


    return response.toBuilder()
            .body(bytes)
            .build();
 }
}
```

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/send/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
SendEmailRemoteResponse  hello(@PathVariable("name") List<String> name);

Comment: hello, what's this? @Araf

Comment: Please add /{name} in @GetMapping annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Registering a `feign.Logger` instance will handle this for you.

```
@Bean
public Logger logger() {
    /* here are the two built in loggers */
    return new JavaLogger(); // for java.util.logging

    /* may require feign-slf4j */
    return new Slf4jLogger(); // if you want to use slf4j
}
```

The `Logger` will log the request and the response for you, including the resolved path parameters and headers.  Take a look at the [SLF4J Documentation](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#slf4j) on Feign for more tips